# Why do I get this Type conversion error

Tags: c++, arm, gnu, stm32ldiscovery

I get this compiler error 
*../include/BlinkLed.h:46:68: error: conversion to 'uint16_t {aka short unsigned int}' from 'int' may alter its value [-Werror=conversion]*

When I pass the **pin** as u16 type on GPIO_SetBit/GPIO_ResetBits functions,

If I call the same funciton(s) with constant values eg.

GPIO_SetBits(BLINK_GPIOx(BLINK_PORT_NUMBER),BLINK_PIN_MASK(15));
the program  compile and runs fine.
How do I avoid this compilation error but yet pass the pin as a parameter.

```
 //
    // This file is part of the GNU ARM Eclipse distribution.
    // Copyright (c) 2014 Liviu Ionescu.
    //

    #ifndef BLINKLED_H_
    #define BLINKLED_H_

    #include "stm32f30x.h"
    #include "diag/Trace.h"

    // ----- LED definitions ------------------------------------------------------

    // Adjust these definitions for your own board.

    // STM32F3DISCOVERY definitions (GREEN led, E15, active high)
    // (SEGGER J-Link device name: STM32F303VC).

    // Port numbers: 0=A, 1=B, 2=C, 3=D, 4=E, 5=F, 6=G, ...
    #define BLINK_PORT_NUMBER               (4)
    #define BLINK_PIN_NUMBER                (15)
    #define BLINK_ACTIVE_LOW                (0)

    #define BLINK_GPIOx(_N)                 ((GPIO_TypeDef *)(GPIOA_BASE + (GPIOB_BASE-GPIOA_BASE)*(_N)))
    #define BLINK_PIN_MASK(_N)              (1 << (_N))
    #define BLINK_RCC_MASKx(_N)             (RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA << (_N))
    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    class BlinkLed
    {
    public:
      BlinkLed() = default;

      void
      powerUp(u16 pin);

      inline void
      __attribute__((always_inline))
      turnOn(u16 pin)
      {
          trace_printf("turn on %u\n", pin);
    #if (BLINK_ACTIVE_LOW)
        GPIO_ResetBits(BLINK_GPIOx(BLINK_PORT_NUMBER),
           BLINK_PIN_MASK( pin));
    #else
        GPIO_SetBits(BLINK_GPIOx(BLINK_PORT_NUMBER),BLINK_PIN_MASK(pin));
    #endif
      }*emphasized text*

      inline void
      __attribute__((always_inline))
      turnOff(u16 pin)
      {
    #if (BLINK_ACTIVE_LOW)
        GPIO_SetBits(BLINK_GPIOx(BLINK_PORT_NUMBER),
            pin);
    #else
        GPIO_ResetBits(BLINK_GPIOx(BLINK_PORT_NUMBER),
            pin);
    #endif
      }
    };

    // ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

    #endif // BLINKLED_H_


The functions GPIO_SetBits/GPIO_ResetBits are declared as

/**
  ******************************************************************************
  * @file    stm32f30x_gpio.c
  * @author  MCD Application Team
  * @version V1.0.1
  * @date    23-October-2012
  * @brief   This file provides firmware functions to manage the following 
  *          functionalities of the GPIO peripheral:
  *           + Initialization and Configuration functions
  *           + GPIO Read and Write functions
  *           + GPIO Alternate functions configuration functions
  *
  *  @verbatim


 ===============================================================================
                      ##### How to use this driver #####
 ===============================================================================
    [..]
    (#) Enable the GPIO AHB clock using RCC_AHBPeriphClockCmd()
    (#) Configure the GPIO pin(s) using GPIO_Init()
        Four possible configuration are available for each pin:
        (++) Input: Floating, Pull-up, Pull-down.
        (++) Output: Push-Pull (Pull-up, Pull-down or no Pull),
                     Open Drain (Pull-up, Pull-down or no Pull).
             In output mode, the speed is configurable: Low, Medium, Fast or High.
        (++) Alternate Function: Push-Pull (Pull-up, Pull-down or no Pull), 
                                 Open Drain (Pull-up, Pull-down or no Pull).
        (++) Analog: required mode when a pin is to be used as ADC channel,
             DAC output or comparator input.
    (#) Peripherals alternate function:
        (++) For ADC, DAC and comparators, configure the desired pin in 
             analog mode using GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AN
        (++) For other peripherals (TIM, USART...):
             (+++) Connect the pin to the desired peripherals' Alternate 
                   Function (AF) using GPIO_PinAFConfig() function.
             (+++) Configure the desired pin in alternate function mode using
                   GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF
             (+++) Select the type, pull-up/pull-down and output speed via 
                   GPIO_PuPd, GPIO_OType and GPIO_Speed members.
             (+++) Call GPIO_Init() function.
    (#) To get the level of a pin configured in input mode use GPIO_ReadInputDataBit()
    (#) To set/reset the level of a pin configured in output mode use
        GPIO_SetBits()/GPIO_ResetBits()
    (#) During and just after reset, the alternate functions are not active 
        and the GPIO pins are configured in input floating mode (except JTAG pins).
    (#) The LSE oscillator pins OSC32_IN and OSC32_OUT can be used as 
        general-purpose (PC14 and PC15, respectively) when the LSE
        oscillator is off. The LSE has priority over the GPIO function.
    (#) The HSE oscillator pins OSC_IN/OSC_OUT can be used as general-purpose 
        (PF0 and PF1 respectively) when the HSE oscillator is off. The HSE has 
        the priority over the GPIO function.  

  @endverbatim

  ******************************************************************************
  * @attention
  *
  * <h2><center>&copy; COPYRIGHT 2012 STMicroelectronics</center></h2>
  *
  * Licensed under MCD-ST Liberty SW License Agreement V2, (the "License");
  * You may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  * You may obtain a copy of the License at:
  *
  *        http://www.st.com/software_license_agreement_liberty_v2
  *
  * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software 
  * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, 
  * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  * limitations under the License.
  *
  ******************************************************************************
  */

    /* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
    #include "stm32f30x_gpio.h"
    #include "stm32f30x_rcc.h"

    /** @addtogroup STM32F30x_StdPeriph_Driver
      * @{
      */

    /** @defgroup GPIO 
      * @brief GPIO driver modules
      * @{
      */


    /* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/


    /* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
    /* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
    /* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/

    /** @defgroup GPIO_Private_Functions 
      * @{
      */

    /** @defgroup GPIO_Group1 Initialization and Configuration
     *  @brief   Initialization and Configuration
     *
    @verbatim
     ===============================================================================
                ##### Initialization and Configuration #####
     ===============================================================================

    @endverbatim
      * @{
      */

    /**
      * @brief  Deinitializes the GPIOx peripheral registers to their default reset 
      *         values.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A, B, C, D, E or F) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @retval None
      */
    void GPIO_DeInit(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx)
    {
      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));

      if(GPIOx == GPIOA)
      {
        RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, ENABLE);
        RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOA, DISABLE);
      }
      else if(GPIOx == GPIOB)
      {
        RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, ENABLE);
        RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOB, DISABLE);
      }
      else if(GPIOx == GPIOC)
      {
        RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOC, ENABLE);
        RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOC, DISABLE);
      }
      else if(GPIOx == GPIOD)
      {
        RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOD, ENABLE);
        RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOD, DISABLE);
      }
      else if(GPIOx == GPIOE)
      {
        RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOE, ENABLE);
        RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOE, DISABLE);
      }
      else
      {
        if(GPIOx == GPIOF)
        {
          RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOF, ENABLE);
          RCC_AHBPeriphResetCmd(RCC_AHBPeriph_GPIOF, DISABLE);
        }
      }
    }

    // [ILG]
    #if defined ( __GNUC__ )
    #pragma GCC diagnostic push
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
    #endif

    /**
      * @brief  Initializes the GPIOx peripheral according to the specified 
      *         parameters in the GPIO_InitStruct.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A, B, C, D, E or F) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @param  GPIO_InitStruct: pointer to a GPIO_InitTypeDef structure that 
      *         contains the configuration information for the specified GPIO
      *         peripheral.
      * @note   GPIO_Pin: selects the pin to be configured:
      *         GPIO_Pin_0->GPIO_Pin_15 for GPIOA, GPIOB, GPIOC, GPIOD and GPIOE;
      *         GPIO_Pin_0->GPIO_Pin_2, GPIO_Pin_4, GPIO_Pin_6, GPIO_Pin_9 
      *                       and GPIO_Pin_10 for GPIOF.
      * @retval None
      */
    void GPIO_Init(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, GPIO_InitTypeDef* GPIO_InitStruct)
    { 
      uint32_t pinpos = 0x00, pos = 0x00 , currentpin = 0x00;

      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Pin));
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_MODE(GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Mode));
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_PUPD(GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_PuPd));

      /*-------------------------- Configure the port pins -----------------------*/
      /*-- GPIO Mode Configuration --*/
      for (pinpos = 0x00; pinpos < 0x10; pinpos++)
      {
        pos = ((uint32_t)0x01) << pinpos;

        /* Get the port pins position */
        currentpin = (GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Pin) & pos;

        if (currentpin == pos)
        {
          if ((GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Mode == GPIO_Mode_OUT) || (GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Mode == GPIO_Mode_AF))
          {
            /* Check Speed mode parameters */
            assert_param(IS_GPIO_SPEED(GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Speed));

            /* Speed mode configuration */
            GPIOx->OSPEEDR &= ~(GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR0 << (pinpos * 2));
            GPIOx->OSPEEDR |= ((uint32_t)(GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Speed) << (pinpos * 2));

            /* Check Output mode parameters */
            assert_param(IS_GPIO_OTYPE(GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_OType));

            /* Output mode configuration */
            GPIOx->OTYPER &= ~((GPIO_OTYPER_OT_0) << ((uint16_t)pinpos));
            GPIOx->OTYPER |= (uint16_t)(((uint16_t)GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_OType) << ((uint16_t)pinpos));
          }

          GPIOx->MODER  &= ~(GPIO_MODER_MODER0 << (pinpos * 2));

          GPIOx->MODER |= (((uint32_t)GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Mode) << (pinpos * 2));

          /* Pull-up Pull down resistor configuration */
          GPIOx->PUPDR &= ~(GPIO_PUPDR_PUPDR0 << ((uint16_t)pinpos * 2));
          GPIOx->PUPDR |= (((uint32_t)GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_PuPd) << (pinpos * 2));
        }
      }
    }

    // [ILG]
    #if defined ( __GNUC__ )
    #pragma GCC diagnostic pop
    #endif

    /**
      * @brief  Fills each GPIO_InitStruct member with its default value.
      * @param  GPIO_InitStruct: pointer to a GPIO_InitTypeDef structure which will 
      *         be initialized.
      * @retval None
      */
    void GPIO_StructInit(GPIO_InitTypeDef* GPIO_InitStruct)
    {
      /* Reset GPIO init structure parameters values */
      GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Pin  = GPIO_Pin_All;
      GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_IN;
      GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_2MHz;
      GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_OType = GPIO_OType_PP;
      GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_PuPd = GPIO_PuPd_NOPULL;
    }

    /**
      * @brief  Locks GPIO Pins configuration registers.
      *         The locked registers are GPIOx_MODER, GPIOx_OTYPER, GPIOx_OSPEEDR,
      *         GPIOx_PUPDR, GPIOx_AFRL and GPIOx_AFRH.
      * @note   The configuration of the locked GPIO pins can no longer be modified
      *         until the next reset.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A or B or D) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @param  GPIO_Pin: specifies the port bit to be written.
      *   This parameter can be any combination of GPIO_Pin_x where x can be (0..15).
      * @retval None
      */
    void GPIO_PinLockConfig(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
    {
      uint32_t tmp = 0x00010000;

      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_LIST_PERIPH(GPIOx));
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));

      tmp |= GPIO_Pin;
      /* Set LCKK bit */
      GPIOx->LCKR = tmp;
      /* Reset LCKK bit */
      GPIOx->LCKR =  GPIO_Pin;
      /* Set LCKK bit */
      GPIOx->LCKR = tmp;
      /* Read LCKK bit */
      tmp = GPIOx->LCKR;
      /* Read LCKK bit */
      tmp = GPIOx->LCKR;
    }

    /**
      * @}
      */

    /** @defgroup GPIO_Group2 GPIO Read and Write
     *  @brief    GPIO Read and Write
     *
    @verbatim
     ===============================================================================
                      ##### GPIO Read and Write #####
     ===============================================================================  

    @endverbatim
      * @{
      */   

    /**
      * @brief  Reads the specified input port pin.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A, B, C, D, E or F) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @param  GPIO_Pin: specifies the port bit to read.
      * @note   This parameter can be GPIO_Pin_x where x can be :
      *         (0..15) for GPIOA, GPIOB, GPIOC, GPIOD or GPIOE;
      *         (0..2, 4, 6, 9..10) for GPIOF.
      * @retval The input port pin value.
      */
    uint8_t GPIO_ReadInputDataBit(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
    {
      uint8_t bitstatus = 0x00;

      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));
      assert_param(IS_GET_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));

      if ((GPIOx->IDR & GPIO_Pin) != (uint32_t)Bit_RESET)
      {
        bitstatus = (uint8_t)Bit_SET;
      }
      else
      {
        bitstatus = (uint8_t)Bit_RESET;
      }
      return bitstatus;
    }

    /**
      * @brief  Reads the specified input port pin.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A, B, C, D, E or F) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @retval The input port pin value.
      */
    uint16_t GPIO_ReadInputData(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx)
    {
      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));

      return ((uint16_t)GPIOx->IDR);
    }

    /**
      * @brief  Reads the specified output data port bit.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A, B, C, D, E or F) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @param  GPIO_Pin: Specifies the port bit to read.
      * @note   This parameter can be GPIO_Pin_x where x can be :
      *         (0..15) for GPIOA, GPIOB, GPIOC, GPIOD or GPIOE;
      *         (0..2, 4, 6, 9..10) for GPIOF.
      * @retval The output port pin value.
      */
    uint8_t GPIO_ReadOutputDataBit(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
    {
      uint8_t bitstatus = 0x00;

      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));
      assert_param(IS_GET_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));

      if ((GPIOx->ODR & GPIO_Pin) != (uint32_t)Bit_RESET)
      {
        bitstatus = (uint8_t)Bit_SET;
      }
      else
      {
        bitstatus = (uint8_t)Bit_RESET;
      }
      return bitstatus;
    }

    /**
      * @brief  Reads the specified GPIO output data port.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A, B, C, D, E or F) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @retval GPIO output data port value.
      */
    uint16_t GPIO_ReadOutputData(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx)
    {
      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));

      return ((uint16_t)GPIOx->ODR);
    }

    /**
      * @brief  Sets the selected data port bits.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A, B, C, D, E or F) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @param  GPIO_Pin: specifies the port bits to be written.
      * @note   This parameter can be GPIO_Pin_x where x can be :
      *         (0..15) for GPIOA, GPIOB, GPIOC, GPIOD or GPIOE;
      *         (0..2, 4, 6, 9..10) for GPIOF.
      * @retval None
      */
    void GPIO_SetBits(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
    {
      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));
      //assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));

      GPIOx->BSRR = GPIO_Pin;
    }

    /**
      * @brief  Clears the selected data port bits.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A, B, C, D, E or F) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @param  GPIO_Pin: specifies the port bits to be written.
      * @note   This parameter can be GPIO_Pin_x where x can be :
      *         (0..15) for GPIOA, GPIOB, GPIOC, GPIOD or GPIOE;
      *         (0..2, 4, 6, 9..10) for GPIOF.
      * @retval None
      */
    void GPIO_ResetBits(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin)
    {
      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));

      GPIOx->BRR = GPIO_Pin;
    }

    /**
      * @brief  Sets or clears the selected data port bit.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A, B, C, D, E or F) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @param  GPIO_Pin: specifies the port bit to be written.
      * @note   This parameter can be GPIO_Pin_x where x can be :
      *         (0..15) for GPIOA, GPIOB, GPIOC, GPIOD or GPIOE;
      *         (0..2, 4, 6, 9..10) for GPIOF.
      * @param  BitVal: specifies the value to be written to the selected bit.
      *   This parameter can be one of the BitAction enumeration values:
      *     @arg Bit_RESET: to clear the port pin
      *     @arg Bit_SET: to set the port pin
      * @retval None
      */
    void GPIO_WriteBit(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_Pin, BitAction BitVal)
    {
      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));
      assert_param(IS_GET_GPIO_PIN(GPIO_Pin));
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_BIT_ACTION(BitVal));

      if (BitVal != Bit_RESET)
      {
        GPIOx->BSRR = GPIO_Pin;
      }
      else
      {
        GPIOx->BRR = GPIO_Pin ;
      }
    }

    /**
      * @brief  Writes data to the specified GPIO data port.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A, B, C, D, E or F) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @param  PortVal: specifies the value to be written to the port output data 
      *                  register.
      * @retval None
      */
    void GPIO_Write(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t PortVal)
    {
      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));

      GPIOx->ODR = PortVal;
    }

    /**
      * @}
      */

    /** @defgroup GPIO_Group3 GPIO Alternate functions configuration functions
     *  @brief   GPIO Alternate functions configuration functions
     *
    @verbatim
     ===============================================================================
              ##### GPIO Alternate functions configuration functions #####
     ===============================================================================

    @endverbatim
      * @{
      */

    /**
      * @brief  Writes data to the specified GPIO data port.
      * @param  GPIOx: where x can be (A, B, C, D, E or F) to select the GPIO peripheral.
      * @param  GPIO_PinSource: specifies the pin for the Alternate function.
      *   This parameter can be GPIO_PinSourcex where x can be (0..15).
      * @param  GPIO_AF: selects the pin to be used as Alternate function.  
      *   This parameter can be one of the following value:
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_0:  JTCK-SWCLK, JTDI, JTDO/TRACESW0, JTMS-SWDAT, MCO, NJTRST, 
      *                      TRACED, TRACECK.
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_1:  OUT, TIM2, TIM15, TIM16, TIM17.
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_2:  COMP1_OUT, TIM1, TIM2, TIM3, TIM4, TIM8, TIM15.
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_3:  COMP7_OUT, TIM8, TIM15, Touch.
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_4:  I2C1, I2C2, TIM1, TIM8, TIM16, TIM17.
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_5:  IR_OUT, I2S2, I2S3, SPI1, SPI2, TIM8, USART4, USART5
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_6:  IR_OUT, I2S2, I2S3, SPI2, SPI3, TIM1, TIM8
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_7:  AOP2_OUT, CAN, COMP3_OUT, COMP5_OUT, COMP6_OUT, USART1, 
      *                      USART2, USART3.
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_8:  COMP1_OUT, COMP2_OUT, COMP3_OUT, COMP4_OUT, COMP5_OUT, 
      *                      COMP6_OUT.
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_9:  AOP4_OUT, CAN, TIM1, TIM8, TIM15.
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_10: AOP1_OUT, AOP3_OUT, TIM2, TIM3, TIM4, TIM8, TIM17. 
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_11: TIM1, TIM8.
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_12: TIM1.
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_14: USBDM, USBDP.
      *     @arg GPIO_AF_15: OUT.             
      * @note  The pin should already been configured in Alternate Function mode(AF)
      *        using GPIO_InitStruct->GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF
      * @note  Refer to the Alternate function mapping table in the device datasheet 
      *        for the detailed mapping of the system and peripherals alternate 
      *        function I/O pins.
      * @retval None
      */
    void GPIO_PinAFConfig(GPIO_TypeDef* GPIOx, uint16_t GPIO_PinSource, uint8_t GPIO_AF)
    {
      uint32_t temp = 0x00;
      uint32_t temp_2 = 0x00;

      /* Check the parameters */
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_ALL_PERIPH(GPIOx));
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_PIN_SOURCE(GPIO_PinSource));
      assert_param(IS_GPIO_AF(GPIO_AF));

      temp = ((uint32_t)(GPIO_AF) << ((uint32_t)((uint32_t)GPIO_PinSource & (uint32_t)0x07) * 4));
      GPIOx->AFR[GPIO_PinSource >> 0x03] &= ~((uint32_t)0xF << ((uint32_t)((uint32_t)GPIO_PinSource & (uint32_t)0x07) * 4));
      temp_2 = GPIOx->AFR[GPIO_PinSource >> 0x03] | temp;
      GPIOx->AFR[GPIO_PinSource >> 0x03] = temp_2;
    }

    /**
      * @}
      */

    /**
      * @}
      */

    /**
      * @}
      */

    /**
      * @}
      */

    /************************ (C) COPYRIGHT STMicroelectronics *****END OF FILE****/
```

Comment: What type are GPIO_ResetBits and GPIO_SetBits?

Comment: @immibis ,uint16_t or u16 , thanks

Comment: Literal `1` is of type `int`, and so the expression `(1 << (pin))` is also of type `int`. For all the compiler knows, `pin > 16` and the result of the shift won't fit in `u16`. When you use a constant in place of the variable, the compiler can perform the calculation at compile time and see that it does not in fact overflow.

Comment: Conversion of `int` to an unsigned type is well-defined except for narrowing conversion in braces list initialization. So you're apparently using compiler options that explicitly ask it to be far more restrictive than the standard, in which case, fix those options. However, I haven't read that massive avalanche of code.

Comment: @Alf, Thanks, indeed it is the very nature of the GNU compiler, that cause the issue. adding these pragma resolved the issue. #if defined ( __GNUC__ )
    #pragma GCC diagnostic push
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
#endif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this pragma resloved the issue;

```
#if defined ( __GNUC__ )
    #pragma GCC diagnostic push
    #pragma GCC diagnostic ignored "-Wconversion"
#endif
```

and  do **diagnostic pop** when you want to bring back pushed directives